# Unity WebGL communicate with web page

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am noob at unity. So, I am trying my best to explain the problem where I am stuck and I have no clue how to approach. I have a Ruby on Rails website running.

I am building a small game on unity which is much like an inventory management system. But, the inventory is specific to a user and the user can make changes to it. The user sees the game as a part of his dashboard.
What I want to do:

1. The moment the user lands on his dashboard, the unity game should load with the signed in users inventory.
2. For this, I believe the unity webgl needs to interact with my application and get the user.

Also,

3. How can I test all this without having to build the application?

Comment: this question belongs to [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: okay. posted there. thanks

Comment: The user has to sign in with username and password? "I believe the unity webgl needs to interact with my application?" which application?

Comment: Yes needs to sign in with username and password.

I am running a RoR website i.e. application

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate directly with the browser, then

> from **WebGL** to **index.html** - Application.ExternalCall("MyFunction", MyValue)
>
> from **index.html** to **WebGL** - SendMessage("MyGameObject","MyFunction", MyValue)

So in your case the moment user land on his dashboard the unity should get something like id of user sign-in from browser which is need to call function from index.html and return it back to unity with the data you get from session.

**WebGL**

```
public void ReloadInventoryBaseOnUser()
{
    Application.ExternalCall("GetUserID");
}
```

**index.html**

```
function GetUserID(){
    //$.ajax here to get session id
    SendMessage("Manager","SetUserID", userID);
    focus();
}
```

**WebGL**

```
public void SetUserID(string ID){
    userID = ID;
    ReloadInventory(userID);
}
```

The session is server side thing, You can write an Http handler (that will share the session id if any) and return the value from there using `$.ajax`. so assuming that you have store the id into js variable `userID`

Answer (score 0):

You can test user sign in/sign out and dashboard in the **Editor** without building to **WebGl**. It will work but you should **always** test your game for **WebGl** **once** in a **while** during **development** to make sure that what you are doing will **work** in the future. **Without** doing this, your **final** game **may not** work because you used unsupported API for **WebGL**. That's why you must test the game but no **all** the time, just **once** in a while.

For communication with your server, you should use the new Unity API **UnityWebRequest** instead of **WWW**. The **WWW class** will be removed this month or in the coming months. **UnityWebRequest** fully supports **WebGL** build. **.Net** classes are NOT supported in **WebGL** Build. So you can't use anything like **HttpWebRequest** or **Sockets**...

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Actually, I dont need to communicate with the server for this problem. I want to communicate with the browser and get the signed in user details i.e. username stored in session. Because, the user has already signed in and is sitting on the dashboard of my website. I want him to automatically reach his inventory on unity game from here.

Comment: I want to know what you are cable of. Did you program the dashboard?